# Return two pointers of arrays

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

To summarize my problem,
i want an array to return two array pointers. One of these pointer arrays must be float or double, this will give me the quotient operation. Another should be int, and that should give the remainder of the division. 
For examle if i have two arrays as: `int a[] = {3,6,9,12,16,18}, b[] = {2,3,3,4,4,4};` when i want to reach my pointers result should be like: `Quotient is: {1.5,2,3,3,4,4.5} Remainder is: {1,0,0,0,0,2}` 
**Here is my codes:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void div(int a[], int b[], float *quotient, int *remainder) {
    float quo[6];
    int remain[6];

    for(int i = 0; i< 6 ; i++)
    {
        quo[i] = a[i] / (double)b[i];
        remain[i] = a[i] % b[i];
        *remainder = remain[i];
        *quotient = quo[i];
        *remainder++;
        *quotient++;
    }

   // quotient = quo;
   // remainder = remain;
 
}

int main() {

    int a[] = {3,6,9,12,16,18}, b[] = {2,3,3,4,4,4};
    float q;
    int r;
  
    div(a, b, &q, &r);

    for(int i = 0; i< 6 ; i++)
    {

        printf("Quotient is: %.1f\nRemainder is: %d\n", q, r);
    } 


 //  printf("Quotient is: %.1f\nRemainder is: %d\n", *q, *r);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `main` should declare `q` and `r` as arrays, and pass them to the function (just like `a` and `b`). The function just fills in the values.

Comment: I'm sorry but im new in C. Can you please show me in code and lead the way about the solution to the problem? @user3386109

Comment: Do this change: `float q[6]` and `int r[6]` and in print use `q[i]` and `r[i]`.

Comment: There is no question in your post. Ask an explicit question.

Comment: @Eraklon thank you so much it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an array for the quotient and remainder into the divide function.
Than you can read the values after the function returns.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void div(int* a, int* b, float* quotient, int* remainder, int count) {

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        quotient[i] = a[i] / (double)b[i];
        remainder[i] = a[i] % b[i];
    }
}


int main() {

    int a[] = { 3,6,9,12,16,18 }, b[] = { 2,3,3,4,4,4 };

#define LENGTH  (sizeof(a) / sizeof(int))
    
    float quotient[LENGTH];
    int remainder[LENGTH];


    div(a, b, quotient, remainder, LENGTH);

    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
    {

        printf("Quotient is: %.1f\nRemainder is: %d\n", quotient[i], remainder[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```